# SymmetricDS Spring boot with Embedded Clients

Tags: java, spring-boot, symmetricds

Is it possible to have only Client type nodes?

When my Spring boot app start as with SymmetricDS Client I see the following in the log:

```
SymmetricDS: type=client......
```

What if all the nodes will sync with each other and there won't be a server?

I have the following code:

```
public ClientNode(File file) throws IOException {
    propFile = file;
    Properties propertiesFile = new Properties();
    propertiesFile.load(new FileReader(propFile));
    cEngine = new ClientSymmetricEngine(propertiesFile, false);
    getcEngine().setup();
    getcEngine().openRegistration("client", "001");
    getcEngine().start();
}
```

How will they register each other? I have the following properties:

```
external.id=001
engine.name=client-001
sync.url=http://localhost:8080/sync/client-001
group.id=client
db.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000
db.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.user=USER
registration.url=http://localhost:31415/sync/server
db.password=PW
job.routing.period.time.ms=5000
job.push.period.time.ms=10000
job.pull.period.time.ms=10000
initial.load.create.first=true
auto.config.database=true

 #I was hoping this will make it register
auto.registration=true
auto_reload=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll need to promote of one the nodes to a server. It will be served to configure the system and to register all clients against

Comment: How do I do that from config?
I have a server and a client node in Spring boot. 
Both are client nodes but the server is configured to have no registration.url.

I start both Spring boot apps, and the standalone SymmetricDS server with the 2 configs.
And both client and server starts as a client type as well.

Comment: Could you share the details of the configuration of both server and client by editing the original question?